# GWT RPC SerializationException

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc, objectify

I am trying to send an object across GWT RPC (GWT 2.4). The object includes an object which includes the following field:

```
@Serialized
private Map<Class<? extends Foo>, Foo> fooMap = ImmutableMap.of();
```

`Foo` is defined as:

```
public interface Foo extends Serializable {

}
```

When `fooMap` is empty, it works fine. When it is populated, the GWT RPC fails with a `SerializationException`. (The server is never hit.) The only type of `Foo` in `fooMap` is from this class:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private long bar;
  private float baz;
  private int batz;

  ... 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? `FooImpl` shouldn't be causing any problems. Every class has a no-arg constructor. I don't need getters and setters for every private field of every serialized object, right? Is `Class<? extends Foo>` a problem?

Comment: Where is the definition of the object itself? Does it contain anything besides your `fooMap`?

Comment: the object itself is `Serializable`, and works fine when `fooMap` is removed or is empty.

Comment: My inclination is to look at the GWT-serialization characteristics of the Map implementation you are using.

Comment: Try to manually create default constructor for Class FooImpl. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class<? extends Foo>` is most likely a problem. As far as I know GWT simply don't know how to serialize-deserialize `Class` instance (it has code only for serializing normal objects, enums and arrays and there is no CustomFieldSerializer). So try to use classnames instead of `Class` instances.